# In D using the std.regex library, how do you match a dot?

Tags: regex, d

This may sound like a silly question but in [D](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/D_%28programming_language%29) (using [std.regex](http://d.digitalmars.com/2.0/phobos/std_regex.html)) how do you match a literal dot in a string?

Using this code i'm checking for the file extension .bmp so i perform a simple regex match on it. If i try and escape the dot like this i get an error.

```
Regex!char Pattern = regex("\.bmp$", "i");

if (match(FileName, Pattern).empty)
{
    FileName ~= ".bmp";
}
```

`Error: Undefined escape sequence \.`

Even in the [documentation](http://d.digitalmars.com/2.0/phobos/std_regex.html) it doesn't mention matching dots.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the `$` special in D?

Comment: @fge It's a standard way of matching the end of a string (or line in multi-line mode).

Comment: I know that. I was just wondering whether, by any chance, the D _language_ required escaping it somehow, in order for it to be literal in the string (and therefore `$` in a regex)

Comment: The problem is the single escaping. `\ ` is a special character in the language, and if you want to use that literaly in the regex, you need to escape the escaping character itself.

Comment: You should always use r"" strings with regex.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I guess you need to double escape it (You want `\.` in the regex). In your current code, you are single escaping it, so D tries to interpret it as something for itself, not for regex. Double escaping tells D that you want a literal `\` in the string.

So in the end, it should look like `"\\.bmp$"`.

Comment: +1. It may be useful to be explicit about double-escaping: "\\.bmp$"

Comment: This does work. I've double escaped it and all works fine, thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Your `"\.bmp$"` string is escaped itself, hence the error. D thinks you are trying to escape the `.` in the string, but `\.` isn't a valid escape sequence.

Note that this isn't specific to D; [C++ gives you the same error](http://ideone.com/6joSl).

```
const char* regex = "\.bmp$";
```

Compiling with g++ 4.3.4 gives:

```
prog.cpp:1: error: unknown escape sequence '\.'
```

You have two options:

1. Escape the `\` in your string i.e. `"\\.bmp$"`.
2. Use a raw string literator i.e. `r"\.bmp$"`. Raw string literals ignore all escape sequences. They are designed specifically for things like regex patterns.

Comment: Probably the 'r' token to flag a raw string stands for "raw".  But it's so useful in this context that I always think of it as "R, for regex strings!"

Comment: There is actually more like 6 options in D. I see no need to list them as yours is sufficient.